# Rails -> Devise -> how to access current_user from Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm currently using Rails 3.2.9 with devise 3.0.4

I can access Devise current_user in Controller without any problem.

However, when I'm trying to access current_user in Module as below and receive error.

```
c_time = DateTime.current.in_time_zone(current_user.local_timezone)
```

NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for DateCalculator:Module):

It would be great if someone please advise what's the best way to access current_user from Module.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of using current_user object

```
UserSession.find.user
```

Comment: Hi spkpraveen, thanks for the answer but got below error. NameError (uninitialized constant DateCalculator::UserSession):

Answer (score 0):

If your module does something specific to current signed in user, your can follow this way

```
config/initializers/user_specific_time.rb
module Devise
    module Controllers
        module Helpers
            def user_specific_time
                c_time = DateTime.current.in_time_zone(current_user.local_timezone)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dileep I tried the above but I still couldn't access that method from Module. How should I call that method from Module.

Comment: I suggest putting module logic inside devise helper if its very much dependent on current user. eg: current_locale, curent_time_in_user_time_zone etc

Comment: Actually, it's not very much dependent in that way. I just need for some calculation. Is there other way to get the current_user in Module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gem called **sentient_user** it is a cheeky approach but it does exactly what you need ;) which is to have access to current logged in user, from view | Controller | Model etc

```
https://rubygems.org/gems/sentient_user
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give a try. Does this able to call from Module which saved under lib folder.

Comment: Yes this should be able to get the current_user through a Module mixed into your app.